# pyscopg2 select NULL values

Tags: python, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, psycopg2

How do I use [string substitution](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) in Psycopg2 to handle both NULL and non-NULL values?

For example:

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = %s;'
possible_params = [1, None]

for x in possible_params:
    print cur.mogrify(sql,(x,))
```

I need the first query to look like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = 1;` And the second to be the functional equivalent of `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col IS NULL;`

Is there a trick? I have many columns that may be NULL or have a value so building the SQL dynamically is fairly cumbersome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time you don't know if a parameter will be `NULL` you can use the following pattern:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = <parameter> OR (col IS NULL AND <parameter> IS NULL)
```

where `<parameter>` is your parameter.

But note that I am using the same parameter two times in a row, so you need to switch to the the `dict` format. The full code is:

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = %(p)s OR (col IS NULL AND %(p)s IS NULL)'
possible_params = [{"p":1}, {"p":None}]

for x in possible_params:
    print cur.mogrify(sql,(x,))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything I could think of:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE col = Null;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE col::TEXT = '';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE col IN (Null::TEXT);
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE col IN (VALUES (NULL::TEXT));
```

and then just mashed kludgy if statements, e.g.:

```
if record['api'] is not None:
    sql += 'api = %(api)s'
else:
    sql += 'api IS NULL'
```